# Way to apply CSS when the component is disabled

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a FormControlLabel and Switch component in my application.

When I disable the Switch, the label in FormControlLabel and button in Switch will become gray color. I would like to **keep the color in both label(Black) and button(Red).**

I have write the following style for testing.

Here is the full code: https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-cherry-f0q5h?file=/src/App.js

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  disabled: { color: "red" }
});

<FormControlLabel classes={{disabled: classes.disabled}}/>
<Switch classes={{disabled: classes.disabled}}/>
```

I expect the classes.disabled will be apply (make the label and button become red) when Switch is disabled, but it did not. What should I do to reach my goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @camper mention you should change your style like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    disabled: {
      '&$disabled': {
        color: 'red',
      },
    }
  });
```

Check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/async-shape-dcrnn?file=/src/App.js:166-277)!

Comment: Great!!!  1 more question, what is '&$disabled' mean?

Comment: > The disabled attribute can be set to keep a user from using the
> element until some other condition has been met (like selecting a
> checkbox, etc.). Then, a JavaScript could remove the disabled value,
> and make the element usable again.
In materialUi you can have access to `disabled` attribute as I told you above `&$disabled`

Answer (score 1):

Plz try to do like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
      '&$disabled': {
        color: 'red',
      },
    },
});

<FormControlLabel classes={{root: classes.root}}/>
<Switch classes={{root: classes.root}}/>
```

Comment: Did you set the disabled attribute of FormControlLabel and Switch to true?

Comment: Yes, i did. The disabled attribute is true